# Evaluate and track/plot of TimeSeriesSplit

Tags: python, datetime, xgboost

I have got time series data. So I used TimeSeriesSplit with 3 splits for XGBRegressor, see the following code.

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
    from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    import math

    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
    print(tscv)

    X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
    y = data.iloc[:, -1].values 

    for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

    X_test = X[test_index]
    X_train = X[train_index]

    y_test = y[test_index]
    y_train = y[train_index]

    model = XGBRegressor()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred_test = model.predict(X_test)
    rmse = (math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_test)))
    print(rmse)
```

My questions are:

1) Is the rmse result already the mean result of the 3 values? If it´s just the result of one fold, how can I show the results of the other 2 to calculate the average?

2) How can I track the validation rmse of each fold to plot the training/ test curve to check over-/ underfitting? Without TimeSeriesSplit I defined

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)],
          eval_metric=['rmse'],verbose=True)
```

So I got:

```
[1]     validation_0-rmse:0.565858      validation_1-rmse:0.574236
[2]     validation_0-rmse:0.550307      validation_1-rmse:0.567077
[3]     validation_0-rmse:0.53824       validation_1-rmse:0.56323
               ...                            ...
```

Comment: did you get the answer to this by any chance?